# Uniform radial distribution function

Tags: scattering, fourier-transform, correlation-functions, molecular-dynamics

I am attempting to properly account for excluded volume effects on the radial distribution function for a fluid. A correction for these effects has been proposed back in 2000 in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0167-7322(99)00169-5) by Hartnig *et al.* in the Journal of Molecular Liquids. They propose a quantity called uniform radial distribution function, $g_u (r)$, which is defined as:

\begin{equation}
g_u (r) = \frac{V}{(2 \pi)^3} \int P(Q) ~\mathrm{d}^3Q
\tag{1}
\label{uniform}
\end{equation}

where $V$ is the volume where fluid is enclosed, $P(Q)$ is the form factor associated with that volume, and $Q$ is known as the scattering vector, i.e. the reciprocal space variable corresponding to the radial coordinate $r$ in physical space. More information on form factors and scattering vectors is available from NIST [here](https://www.ncnr.nist.gov/staff/hammouda/distance_learning/chapter_27.pdf).

My understanding is that Eqn. \ref{uniform} is some type of inverse Fourier transform because it converts a quantity in reciprocal space (*viz.* $P(Q)$) to a quantity in physical space ($g_u(r)$). I am, however, confused as to why the typical $\exp{(-i Q r)}$ does not appear under the integral. Could someone explain this omission to me?

I am also struggling to perform this integral numerically. I have tried using the `ifft` command in Python's numpy package, but then I get a complex-valued vector for $g_u(r)$, which makes no physical sense. This quantity describes the number density of particles and, therefore, it must be real-valued and non-negative. Any help or tips on how to numerically integrate Eqn. \ref{uniform} in Python, MATLAB, or any other scientific computing software is most welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: A more accessible version of the paper is  [arXiv:cond-mat/0002453](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0002453). Is that integral not simply a three dimensional volume integral? Have you tried quad in python with sufficiently large integration bounds?

Comment: Yes, it is integrating over space, however in reciprocal space. The solution to the integral should be a function of $r$, which is $Q$'s corresponding quantity in physical space. And, that's what I am confused about -- how we get this dependence on $r$, if $r$ does not show on the RHS.

Comment: It is best if you dive into this paper and put into your edited question as many details as you can find. Looking at the integral alone does not tell an outsider how to answer your question and you can barely expect that we read that paper for you before you have done it.

Comment: In particular : does this paper clearly state over what region they do their integration ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can try to include more details. The paper does not give the bounds of integration. My issue, however, is with the procedure of integrating and not the particular problem that is discussed in the linked paper. I provided the paper as a reference if anyone wants to get more background on this integral.